# What are Relational, Naming and Petite words?

Tags: word-property, language

This puzzle is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what%20is%20a%22%20word%20is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What%20is%20%22%20%22Word%22%20-missing%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) puzzles.

---

Relational, Naming and Petite Words™ satisfy some properties that other words do not (respectively)

| These are Relational Words™. | Not these. |
| --- | --- |
| place | where |
| into | out |
| lustre | luster |
| since | despite |
| rectangle | quadrilateral |
| gusto | passion |

| These are Naming Words™. | Not these. |
| --- | --- |
| drab | bright |
| sister | brother |
| step | stepped |
| moment | before |
| poster | billboard |
| at | place |

| These are Petite Words™. | Not these. |
| --- | --- |
| to | at |
| be | is |
| a | an |
| do | does |
| za | pizza |
| no | yes |

Question: What are the rules which determins whether a word is a Relational/Naming/Petite Word™ respectively?

Hints:

> This sequence of words may help you: pa, ray, she…

> If pronounced correctly, ray should be 12 spaces ahead.